# Builds executed on the hosted build agent fail

Tags: tfs, msbuild, azure-devops

I'm trying to build my application using Visual Studio Team Services and using the hosted agent pool. It's a simple application with one console application and one test application. It always failing. I'm using standard build configuration
from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/vs/define-build

I'm pasting build summary on the following link.

[build summary print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPppd.png)

My questions:

1. Where are build logs? There are no issues on the summary and 
   If I click 'Download all logs as zip' I get an empty folder.
2. Microsoft announced new script build system which I'm trying to use.
   Are there any restrictions of using it?

Comment: What tasks are you using?

Comment: Is the "Requested by" name on the screenshot erased by you or it is empty by default?

Comment: Do you see live console output at all?  Does it reproduce?  Basically, it means the agent went down (crashed etc...) which means of course it can't send or hasn't uploaded the logs.

Comment: mail me the account name and build #s etc...  it's my username here at microsoft

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the build was failing and the folder with the "Logs" was empty. I tried a lot of things but finally I just had to change the *Build job authorization scope* from *Project Collection* to *Current Project* in the *General* tab of the build. Then the build worked.

You can see a screen shot about it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZmjT.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbar, next to "Queue New Build..." under the build number, you can see a button for downloading the build logs.  Here's your screenshot:

[image: Download Build Logs from Visual Studio Team Services]

To answer your second question, what type of restrictions were you thinking of?  I don't know of any restrictions off the top of my head.  You can use it in the manner you are description in your original question.

Comment: He said that "download logs" gives him an empty zip file. I've seen this issue before, but only with on-prem build agents where the agent service account isn't a member of the build service account group.

Comment: @DanielMann ah thanks for the clarification.  Let me see if I can send to a few folks from the build team to see if they have any ideas.